# vsto and office web addin in same ribbon tab

Tags: vsto, office-js

Is it possible to add buttons from two different addins (one office web addin, and the other VSTO addin) in the same custom ribbon tab in office 2016?
If yes, how?

Comment: I don't know much about web add-ins, but you could try what's here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2008/03/10/share-a-ribbon-customization-between-office-applications-norm-estabrook/

Comment: I've added a uservoice request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/34925413-extend-the-ribbon-xml-for-office-js-to-support-s

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but this should be something you can determine by a quick test. Define a tab/button in VSTO and then define an Add-in Command for the web add-in and use the exact the same name for the tab in the manifest of the web add-in. I suspect you'll get a two tabs with the same name.

Comment: Rick, in the COM world this can be achieved by using a `Qid` instead of `id` for a Ribbon component that can be shared - and that's the only way. I don't see `Qid` anywhere in the Ribbon information for the Office JS model, but I also haven't been able to locate a full schema for valid Ribbon definitions? Assuming it's not there, would there be any plans to add it?

Comment: As far as I know there are no plans to do this. You might want to request it on https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks, Rick. For you and anyone else reading, sorry, my brain was mis-firing: the attribute name that allows sharing is `idQ`...