# officejs addin - is it possible to share a ribbon with a vsto application?

Tags: office365, vsto, office-js

VSTO addins can use `idQ` to share ribbons with each other. Can a officejs addin share a ribbon with a VSTO addin too? How about with another officejs addin?

Comment: See the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326377/vsto-and-office-web-addin-in-same-ribbon-tab As far as anyone knows, no, it's not possible. But feel free to up-vote the User Voice submission (link in a comment) because it would be useful, indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that that is not possible at this time. Office Add-ins use a different system for customizing the ribbon from VSTO. Sharing is not possible, but it is an interesting idea. Please suggest it on [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).